# Preg_match_all not giving the same results as preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to get all file resources inside an HTML.

My current version of the regex is

```
"[^']*'([^"]*)'[^']*"   |   "([^"]*)"
```

An example HTML (only a part):

```
<div style="background-image: url('/courses/UMASGRUPOBDEMO/document/learning_path/El_Contrato_de_Seguro-_Contenido_Teorico/video_pres_cto_seguro.jpg');display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>

                        <img class="maximize"
 src="/courses/CURSODESTINOPEQUENO/document/learning_path/LECCION_1_2_3_4_5_-_corta/Diapositiva01-29332.jpg" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
```

Iterating preg_match I can get:

- /courses/UMASGRUPOBDEMO/document/learning_path/El_Contrato_de_Seguro-_Contenido_Teorico/video_pres_cto_seguro.jpg
- maximize
- /courses/CURSODESTINOPEQUENO/document/learning_path/LECCION_1_2_3_4_5_-_corta/Diapositiva01-29332.jpg

But preg_match_all only give me the next one:

- /courses/UMASGRUPOBDEMO/document/learning_path/El_Contrato_de_Seguro-_Contenido_Teorico/video_pres_cto_seguro.jpg

> You can live test it at http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/h6T

Does this have any sense? Probably my regex needs something to work.

I have not much experience with regex. Please help me :)

Thanks you in advance!

Added:

The regex actually is something like:

- any string delimited by double quotes which contains any string without double quotes and also contains two quotes inside with an optional content in between them
- OR two double quotes with optional content inside (without double quotes)

As I am seeing, maybe the no quotes and no double quotes conditions should be touched a little to have better regex...

Now using a longer HTML example: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/h74

```
<p><img class="maximize" src="/courses/UMASGRUPOBDEMO/document/learning_path/Diapositiva54/Diapositiva2.jpg" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" alt="" /></p>

<div style="background-image: url('/courses/UMASGRUPOBDEMO/document/learning_path/El_Contrato_de_Seguro-_Contenido_Teorico/video_pres_cto_seguro.jpg');display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>

                        <img class="maximize"
 src="/courses/CURSODESTINOPEQUENO/document/learning_path/LECCION_1_2_3_4_5_-_corta/Diapositiva01-29332.jpg" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
```

Comment: First off - please edit your question to add 4 additional spaces after the `>` so that the regular expression does not get formatted.

Comment: Ok, and I have also separated the two parts of the OR so it is seen easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
"[^"']*'([^"']*)'[^"']*"|"([^"]*)"
```

Your original regex was greedily picking up everything from after the second `'` to the *last* `"` in the input.

Remember that the `*` and `+` operators in regex are *greedy* meaning they will consume *as much as possible* in order to match.

You either must limit what those operators are applied to (as I did above) or turn them into non-greedy operators for the regex systems that support it, by using `*?` or `+?`:

```
"[^']*?'[^"]*?'[^']*?"
```

(However, this last one will still have issues, for example with `<img src="foo" alt='bar' class="myimage" />` - which will grab `'bar'` even though it's not part of a `"`-delimited string)

Comment: The first one works like a charm! (as far as I have seen!).
Yeah, the second one needs some work, but I think I get the idea.